# How to remove the computer name, date, and time at the bottom of every printed page

Tags: macos, printing

Recently my computer started printing the my user name, the date, and the time at the bottom of every page I print. I don't want this to be printed. What caused this to happen and how can I stop it? (I am using OS X 10.9.1)

Comment: Does this happen with all apps or just some/one?

Comment: @grgarside This happens with all apps.

Comment: Have you got any printer drivers installed other than the ones that are automatically installed by OS X?

Comment: @grgarside No, I don't

Comment: What kind of printer? When you print to PDF, does the same information appear? In the Print dialog window, do you have the Print headers and footers checkbox checked?

Comment: Does it print the text on a CUPS test page? (open the Print Queue window and go to Printer → Print Test Page)

Comment: What is the make and model of the printer?

Comment: @IconDaemon It shows up when I print to multiple printers types of printers including both network and local printers. It shows up when I print to a PDF. I don't see a "Print headers and footers checkbox" in the print dialog.

Comment: @grgarside It does not show up when I print a test page

Comment: Sorry ... Print headers & footers checkbox is because I was in Google Chrome. Are you printing through a enterprise print server such as PaperCut or Windows print serving at work/school?

Comment: @IconDaemon I am printing to a linux CUPS server.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than guess what has changed, here is a procedure to narrow the cause down.

- Make a new user account from System Preferences and log into that user.
- Open TextEdit and type one word or two and then print.

Don't change any settings and just print one page. If the page prints with the banner, then you can conclude that a system wide print setting has changed or that the printer itself is injecting the footer. The first thing I would try in this case is to reset the printing system:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1341
- If you have printers - option click the - to reset pringing
- if you have no printers, control click the area above the +/- control and reset the printing system

It would be odd to still have banners after resetting the print system and possibly something the print driver is doing automagically.

If not, you can know that it's a print default setting that was entered for your user account.

Comment: It still prints with the banner. The change must be system wide.

Comment: @user2202326 Yes - that's going to be slightly harder to find. Apple's KB article seems a little out of date, so we may need someone to edit things in or a call to AppleCare to clarify things. Do you mind updating if resetting the print system clears the footer?

Comment: Resetting the print system did not fix it.

Comment: Wow - good work. It sure seems like the printer or print queue is likely to be the culprit. If you use the OS X print queue to print a test page and it gets tagged with the footer, I'd be hard pressed to guess how your software was injecting that additional data. If another idea strikes me, I'll report back.